# Update Rejected SSL Error Handler com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewClient

Tags: android-security

I'm trying to solve this problem but unfortunately I can't.

I checked on react-native-webview as indicated by the error:
SSL Error Handler
For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewClient

On RNCWebViewClient it seems that "onReceivedSslError" is handled correctly

you can view the code here:
https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewClient.java

I created an issue but I have not received a response to resolve the problem, at the moment I am in a critical situation I cannot update the application.

link: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/3079

Thank you
Cordially.